# How to pass argument with run <image> to be consumed by Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have this simple Dockefile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
ARG VAR1=initialValue
RUN mkdir $VAR1

ENV VAR2=goodValue
RUN mkdir $VAR2
```

When I **build** the image passing a new value, a **newValue** folder is created

```
docker build --build-arg VAR1=newValue -f Dockerfile -t test  .
```

But when I try to change the value of VAR2 with **run** command, it doesn't work:

```
docker run  -e VAR2=betterValue   test
```

The **goodValue** folder is created. (However, when I *exec* the container and list environmental variables VAR2 is now equal to betterValue.)

How to pass an argument with run  to be consumed by Dockerfile? If it's not possible, what's the workaround?

Comment: You run it *after* it's built, it won't go back through and rebuild with the new env var.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HTYKP3H.png its worked in mycase having bettervalue in ENV

Comment: @Adii  No, it didn't work. You got the new value in echo but Dockerfile used the old value to create the directory in the container. (check with # ls)

Comment: oh you are mixing two thing build stage and running stage. build stage deal with docker file while running only concern with CMD or Entrypoint that's it

Comment: @enhancedJack you can check my answer. at first, I was confused in ur question

Answer (score 1):

You can have a better option I think instead of passing these to docker CMD.
I think this is what you were looking for, to create using env

```
FROM alpine:3.7
ARG VAR1=initialValue
RUN mkdir $VAR1

ENV VAR2=goodValue
RUN mkdir $VAR2
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/ash"]
```

And make the directory in your entry point of docker

```
#!/bin/ash
set -e

if [ "$1" = '/bin/ash' ]; then
    echo "container booting..."
    echo "creating directory having name $VAR2"
    mkdir -p $VAR2
fi

exec "$@"
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice but removes the logic to a script, and I wanted to keep it in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, because you are confusing `Docker's` `build` and `run` stages. Environment variables work fine in fact.

You call `docker run  -e VAR2=betterValue   test` and in fact you get your container running with this value, but directory `goodValue` was created on **build** stage.

You have to:

Call `VAR2=/foo docker build -t test .` you to get your `/foo` folder created at build stage.

Comment: I know that but I hoped it could somehow be done with run as well.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching...

It seems a possible workaround for my example would be to change Dockerfile:

```
    FROM alpine:3.7

    ENTRYPOINT ["mkdir"]  
    CMD ["goodValue"]
```

And then provide a new argument for CMD at the end of **run** command:

```
docker run test betterValue
```